# Breaking the loop

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

I have the following code sample:

```hs
data Smth = A | B

data MyError = MkMyError

data MyState = MkMyState

run :: [Smth] -> Either MyError (Maybe Integer)
run param =
  evalState
    ( foldM
        ( \acc a -> do
            res <- go a
            case res of
              Right (Just _) -> undefined -- I want to break here when Right value is Just
              _ -> return (acc >> res)
        )
        (Right Nothing)
        param
    )
    MkMyState
  where
    go :: Smth -> State MyState (Either MyError (Maybe Integer))
    go = undefined
```

I have list of `Smth` that are processed sequentially and they process a result based on state in the `State` monad and the `Smth` value.

I want to break in the `run` when the `go` results in `MyError` (left value of the `Either`).
This works with the code snippet using the `>>` operator.

However, I want to also have the possibility to break folding when the `go` function results in `Right (Just _)` (There is a comment on the line).

### Question

How to break the following loop when I get the `Just` value?
I want to break the loop in 2 cases:

- in case of error - `go` resulting in `Left` value
- in case of `Just` value - `go` resulting in `Right (Just _)` value. This is some kind of flipped behaviour of the `Maybe` monad and the `>>` operator. I don't want to break on `Nothing`, but on `Just`.

How could this be composed?

Comment: Just look at `acc`. If it's still `Right Nothing`, then do whatever you do, otherwise return `acc`.

Comment: Yeah you are probably right. I don't probably need any monad mechanisms. However, not sure if it will work even for endless `[Smth]` but I'm going to try it out.

Comment: Confirming that it does not properly breaks the loop. In case of endless `[Smth]` it runs forever.
Also, my current solution posted in the question will not properly break in case of `Left` value and it runs forever in case of endless list. It probably needs some kind of monad transformer stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct that you want to process the `Smth`s only as long as `go` keeps returning `Right Nothing`, and stop at the first `go` call that results in `Left _` or `Right (Just _)` without running any more `go` calls?

If so, I don't think your `foldM` makes any sense here.  In case of error or `Just`, you want to stop right away, but the `foldM` just keeps processing `Smth`s after the error or `Just`.  The `acc >> res` makes sure that the fold eventually *returns* the value of the first error, but you still process all the `Smth`s (or run forever, if the input list is infinite).

Instead, you want something like `process`:

```
run :: [Smth] -> Either MyError (Maybe Integer)
run param = evalState (process param) MkMyState
  where
    process :: [Smth] -> State MyState (Either MyError (Maybe Integer))
    process (a:as) = do
      res <- go a
      case res of
        Right Nothing -> process as
        _ -> return res -- stop on Left _ or Right (Just _)
    process [] = return $ Right Nothing

    go :: Smth -> State MyState (Either MyError (Maybe Integer))
    go = undefined
```

If you really want to write `process` as a fold, you can, though it's just a `foldr`, not a `foldM`:

```
process :: [Smth] -> State MyState (Either MyError (Maybe Integer))
process = foldr step (return $ Right Nothing)
  where step a acc = do
          res <- go a
          case res of
            Right Nothing -> acc
            _ -> return res
```